# What is the name of this nesting algorithm?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, parsing, multidimensional-array, nested

I am coding a parser which contains nested scopes. After the parser is done with computing the depths of tokens, I want to nest them in-place to simplify the tokenizer's job.

Considering `{ depth: 1, value: '...' }` simplified as `1`,

`[1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1]` should give `[1, [2, [3, 3], 2], 1 [[3], 2], [1]]`

I reach the desired results with this recursive function (using [lodash](https://lodash.com/), but understandable as vanilla, I suppose):

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1];

var tokens = (function nestDeeperTokens(tokenArray, level){

  var nestedTokens = _.reduce(tokenArray, function(m, v, i){
    if (v == level) { m.push(v); return m; }
    if (_.isArray(_.last(m))) { m[m.length - 1].push(v); return m; }
    m.push([v]); return m;
  }, []);

  return _.map(nestedTokens, function(v){
    return _.isArray(v) ? nestDeeperTokens(v, level + 1) : v;
  });

})(arr, 1);

// => [1, [2, [3, 3], 2], 1 [[3], 2], [1]]
```

Is there a name for this particular pattern/operation? Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: What do those underscores mean? It's the first time I've seen that in JavaScript

Comment: @GuiImamura It's just a variable name, [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/)

Comment: Why/how are you computing the "depth of a token"? Typically nesting is done on-the-go.

Comment: @Bergi In ES6 + lodash, `let tokens = [], depth = 0;
    _.each(line.value.split(/([\{\}])/), (token, i) => {
       if(!token) return;
       if(token === "{") { depth++; return; }
       if(token === "}") { depth--; return; }
       tokens.push({ depth: depth, value: token });
    });`

Comment: Yeah, why don't you simply build the nested arrays in there, instead of computing this `depth` thing?

Comment: @Bergi Good point, it would surely be clearer. I still want to know what is the name for this particular kind of parser though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is worth noting that you are somewhat mixing the roles of the tokenizer and the parser. The "depth" of the token is a parse-time attribute that is not typically labeled during tokenization. Rather, a typical tokenizer would spit out something like (using L and R as imaginary left and right delimiters):

```
[1, L, 2, L, 3, 3, R, 2, R, 1, L, L, 3, R, 2, R, 1]
```

The parser's job would be to create the "hierarchy" and convert this to a meaningful tree-like or nested array structure.

I don't know of an algorithm for the purpose you are mentioning in particular, but I believe what you are looking at in terms of parsers is a left-to-right top-down parser, specifically an [LL(1) parser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LL_parser).